# Comparing multiple words with each other, which also contain digits, and setting them in ascending order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to compare different words with each other. Each word also contains a digit, and I need to put the words in ascending order according to the value of the digits they contain. For example:
sentence = " T4est is2 Thi1s 3a " needs to be put in the following order:
'Thi1s is2 3a T4est'

I tried to find the value of the digits within every word, and then comparing the values of each digit and putting words in the right order in a list. For now, I only could find if a word contains a digit or not. Which returns true or false.

```
import string

sentence = " T4est is2 Thi1s 3a "

def order(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    for word in words:
        if word.isdigit():
            return word

print (order(sentence))
```

For example:
sentence = " T4est is2 Thi1s 3a " needs to be put in the following order:
'Thi1s is2 3a T4est'

Comment: This looks like a school task ;) Interesting though. Anyway we can not just provide solutions here without risking SO to become a free coding facility. But I would be happy to help if you provided some sort of start or some code of yours that we can then work on together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with your lambda function.

```
import re
sentence = " T4est is2 Thi1s 3a "
words = sentence.strip().split(" ")
result = sorted(words, key=lambda x: int(re.search("\d+", x).group()))
# Result here is ['Thi1s', 'is2', '3a', 'T4est']
result = " ".join(result)
print(result)
```

This returns:

```
"Thi1s is2 3a T4est"
```